# Don't show the bounty award link until the waiting period is over?

Tags: bug, user-interface, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If it's too early to award a bounty, indicate so earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78942/if-its-too-early-to-award-a-bounty-indicate-so-earlier)

I got notified that one of the questions I'd put a bounty on was answered, so I read it and decided to award the bounty.  I got the big scary dialog box that my action can never be undone and I clicked on the affirmative button.  And nothing happened.  Oh.  Now there's a yellow box that says `You may award your bounty in 6 hours.`  So why did you make me go through the scary dialog box then?

The simplest solution is to make the link grayed out with hover text that explains the bounty has aged past the waiting period.  A slightly more sophisticated solution would involve a countdown timer and a link to the appropriate FAQ.  But I'd be happy with the text of the dialog box be replaced with `You may award your bounty in 6 hours.`

Comment: And of course I found the (ignored) [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78942/1438) _after_ I asked.