# Add a bounty to any answer

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I remember something about being able to award bounties to any answer... has this feature been removed or is it just hidden in the interface so that I can't find it?

If it was removed, why?  It seemed like a good thing.

See this answer with many bounties given https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54888/139921

Comment: You need to add a bounty to a question before you can award it to an answer. Have you done that yet?

Comment: Exactly my point -- for a while you could give a bounty for any answer even if you didn't create the question.

Comment: @Hogan You aren't getting quite the point: *anyone* with sufficient rep can add a bounty to a question, yes. But you must *add* it before you can *award* it.

Comment: Also; the question must be of a certain age before a bounty can be added to it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - AH!  There is the rub, the question must be old before I can add rep to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of answers (all put in comments):

- You have to wait 3 days before any question can have bounty associated with an answer to this question.
- First you add the bounty to the question, then you can award it to a specific answer.

Comment: And after starting the bounty, you still might need [to wait two days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115343/dont-show-the-bounty-award-link-until-the-waiting-period-is-over) before you can award it to the answer. (And I think one can [start a bounty after 48 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067)?)