# Why does the bounty award button appear on deleted answers?

Tags: support, bounties, user-interface, deleted-answers, user-experience

[image: Bounty option for a deleted answer.]

[image: The standard "are you sure" prompt.]

[image: Tough luck buddy!]

Clearly this is an edge case and I probably shouldn't have even tried awarding the bounty to a deleted answer, but why is the bounty award button even available?

---

It's not a bug since someone added in the notification seen in the final image.  But that sure seems like a roundabout way to let the user know that they can't award a bounty to a deleted answer.  The second step is particularly strange since the system really ought to know that the warning is pointless: no bounty can be awarded.  My suggestion is to rip-off the [Amazon 1-Click patent](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/02/podcast-43-false-facts-blood-feuds/) and let bounties be awarded without the warning.  Then remove the single click button from deleted answers.

Comment: My take on this is that the button is shown on every answer (even if it's classed "deleted"). The actual check, whether or not the bounty can or cannot be awarded for whatever reason, happens server-side. Hence you only see the error after you submit your request, and get a response from the server.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Could be.  I _really_ dislike [that pop-up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78942/1438 "I've changed my mind about how this ought to be fixed.") in any case.

Comment: Considering only 10k users can see deleted answers, you'd expect them to know by now that they can't actually award bounties on them anyways...

Comment: @animuson: They let any old idiot be a 10k user these days. ;-) (Note that I'm not on _any_ site.  Too many bounties.)

Comment: Ultimately, for the same reasons that all the other voting buttons (up, down, and accept) appear on deleted posts. Doesn't make sense to remove one and leave the rest...

Comment: Maybe this should be tagged [tag:bug]

Comment: @animuson No it doesn't make sense to delete the button. But it would be nice to be notified that you can't vote on this deleted post before you receive the warning in the second image. Alternatively you could re-use the implementation that is currently used when the bounty isn't elligeble for awarding yet (first 24 hours).

Answer (score 22):

Same reason the rest of the voting buttons show up.

That said, I agree that telling you you can't award the bounty should probably happen instead of *first* showing you the Big Scary Confirmation.

Comment: Also, the comment that is shown is "The post has been deleted; deleted posts cannot be voted on", instead of something related to the bounty.